# How to return a field from another entity in Odata V4

Tags: c#, odata, odata-v4

I am working on an Odata v4 project and wish to return a field from another table in my result set.

So I have 2 tables

Account:
Id,
Name,
Address,
ColorCode,

Product:
Id,
AccountId

AccountId is a foreign key mapped to the Id field in the Account table

I have the following partial class

```
    public partial class Product

    {   
        public string ColorCode {
            get { return Account.ColorCode; }
        }

public DateTimeOffset? Edmcreated
        {
            get
            {
                return created ;
            }
        }

    }
```

And my controller:

```
 [EnableQuery(PageSize = 200)]
    public IQueryable<Product > Get()
    {
        return _db. Product.AsQueryable();
    }
```

This returns  data from the Product data entity but I cant seem to get the ColorCode  field in the result set.

How can I achieve the above

Comment: can open type and dynamic property help you? 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my answer to your other question: [How to join 2 entities in Odata model builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254991/how-to-join-2-entities-in-odata-model-builder)

And in addition, you don't need to write anything specific for the `$expand` and `$select` in the request URL mentioned in that answer. The `EnableQuery` attribute in the `ProductsController` handles that for you correctly.